# Running JDT compiler from command line with Eclipse configuration file

Tags: java, eclipse-jdt, command-line-tool

[This help page](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/topic/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.user/tasks/tasks-231.htm) describes how to run the Eclipse formatter from the command line, giving it formatting settings exported from Eclipse. This is great, for example, for creating a formatting Ant task that can be run from the command line for this times when you can't/don't want to open the Eclipse GUI. I want to do the same thing, only with the Eclipse JDT compiler.

I've seen [this](http://help.eclipse.org/ganymede/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_api_compile.htm) help page on running ecj.jar, but as far as I can tell it doesn't support taking an Eclipse configuration file as input. I don't want to have to maintain the Eclipse configuration and the command line tool's options in parallel.

Does anyone know of an existing mechanism for compiling with exported Eclipse error/warning settings from the command line?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at

http://help.eclipse.org/helios/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.jdt.doc.isv/guide/jdt_apt_building_with_apt.htm

Does this help you?

Comment: That might be close, except for two things: 1) it appears to target an entire workspace, not a list of source files, or even a single project and 2) that's the guide for APT and it isn't clear to me what the page you referenced means by the word "build" which in  that context I would take to mean "process annotations."